# Select rows in a dataframe based on timeframe of previous rows and other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I attempted to use vectorization with the `shift()` method, but it's not working out. I am trying to keep the row at least 10 minutes greater than the previous entry as long as the SN and shopper column match.

The issue is this code ONLY looks at the row before. Only the ones in red should be removed all other should be kept because the surpasses the 10-minute rule. How can I fix this?

[image: Dataframe]

My code:

```
min_dis = timedelta(minutes = 10)
df = df[~((df['shoppers'] == df['shoppers'].shift()) & (df['Timestamp'].shift() == df['Timestamp']) < min_dis) &  (df['SN'] == )df['SN'].shift())
```

Output should look like this:

[image: Expected output]

Edit: I tried sorting the df by SN and Timestamp but still doesn't solve the issue.

Edit 2:
I don't think I can vectorize this so I am attempting a for loop in which I initialize 2 lists. Grab the last item that fit the criteria, and then run a second loop to append to my final list. I'll post some code as I work it out further

Comment: Can you include your expected output?

Comment: Added expected output.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you keep the last row? 12:10 just three minutes after 12:07 (the previous timestamp for John). Shouldn't you sort your dataframe by time before finding the time differences?

Comment: you are correct. that was an error.  I replaced my expected output.  and yes, I do sort by timestamp first

Answer (score 0):

Your `8/6/22 12:07 d    John    h   845843  8` row doesn't match your requirement because it is only 8 minutes which is less than your 10 minutes requirements.

> I am trying to keep the row at least 10 minutes greater than the previous entry as long as the SN and shopper column match.

Let's first see *the SN and shopper column match* part:

```py
drop_mask = ((df['shoppers'] == df['shoppers'].shift()) & (df['SN'] == df['SN'].shift()))

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Above mask represents the row and its previous row where their SN and shopper column match. The `True` part is where we want to further to check if time satisfies the needs.

By using the `Time_diff` column, we can know which row is less than target minutes and that's the rows we want to drop.

```py
time_mask = (df['Time_diff'] < min_dis)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: Time_diff, dtype: bool
```

However, we don't want to drop all the rows in `time_mask`, we only want to drop the rows whose SN and shopper column matches its previous row. That's what we represent with `drop_mask`

```py
import numpy as np

mask = np.where(drop_mask, np.logical_xor(drop_mask, time_mask), True)

[ True  True  True False False False False  True]
```

At last, you can use this mask to get the keeping rows

```py
df_ = df[mask]

      Timestamp Random shoppers Random2      SN  Time_diff
0  8/6/22-11:25      b     Mark       i  706040        NaN
1  8/6/22-11:30      a     John       h  845843        5.0
2  8/6/22-11:55      c     John       g  845843       15.0
7  8/6/22-12:10      f    Peter       j  635640        5.0
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain correctly.  I'm trying to capture the "8/6/22 12:07" due to it being 12 minutes from the last row that was kept which was "8/6/22 11:55"